# Reading Multiple Integers in Java

Tags: java

> ```
> Input : age of each patron (end of input denoted by a value < 0)
> ```
>
> There are two categories of patrons:
>
> Age 0 through 5 : Kids – no charge($0)
>
> Age 5 through 18 : Students - $5
>
> I am supposed to
>
> Get the age of the patron Determine which category that patron falls
>   into & increase the number for that category
>
> Keep doing steps 1 & 2
>   until the end of input is reached Once end of input is reached •
>
> Calculate the revenue generated for each category (number of patrons
>   in a category * rate for that category)
>
> • Total revenue for the day
>   (sum of revenues of all 4 categories) Generate output in the following
>   format
>
> • Perot Museum :
>
> Today’s Revenue
>
> • Number of kids : *****
>
> • Revenue from kids : $0
>
> • Number of students : ****
>
> • Revenue from students : $****

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            int kidsPrice = 0;
            int studentPrice=5;
            int adultPrice=20;
            int seniorsPrice = 10;
            int numberOfKids =  0; 
            int numberOfStudents = 0;
            int numberOfAdults = 0 ;
            int numberOfSeniors = 0;


            System.out.println("Enter Age ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int numbers = input.nextInt();
            while(input.hasNext()){
                if(numbers >= 0 && numbers <= 5){
                    ++numberOfKids;
                    System.out.println("Number of kids is: " + numberOfKids);
                    System.out.println("Revenue from kids:  " + numberOfKids * kidsPrice);
                }

                if (numbers >= 5 && numbers <= 18){
                    ++numberOfStudents;
                    System.out.println("Number of Students is: " + numberOfStudents);
                    System.out.println("Revenue from Students:  " + numberOfStudents * studentPrice);
                }

                else if (numbers >= 19 && numbers <= 65){
                    ++numberOfAdults;
                    System.out.println("Number of Adults is: " + numberOfAdults);
                    System.out.println("Revenue from Adults:  " + ++numberOfAdults * adultPrice);
                }
                 else if (numbers > 65){
                    ++numberOfSeniors;
                    System.out.println("Number of Seniors is: " + numberOfSeniors);
                    System.out.println("Revenue from Seniors:  " + numberOfSeniors * seniorsPrice);
                }
}
}
```

> The code compiles and runs correctly, however, When I have an input of
>
> 4 6 20 70 5 7 21 72   I get this:   Enter Age  Number of kids is: 1
>
> Revenue from kids:  0 Number of Students is: 1 Revenue from Students:
>
> 5 Number of Adults is: 1 Revenue from Adults:  40 Number of Seniors
>
> is: 1 Revenue from Seniors:  10 Number of kids is: 2 Revenue from
>
> kids:  0 Number of Students is: 2 Revenue from Students:  10 Number of
>
> Students is: 3 Revenue from Students:  15 Number of Adults is: 3
>
> Revenue from Adults:  80 Number of Seniors is: 2 Revenue from Seniors:
>
> 20
>
> How can i make the output just Number of kids is: 2 Revenue from kids:
>
> 0 Number of Students is: 2 Revenue from Students:  10 Number of
>
> Students is: 3 Revenue from Students:  15 Number of Adults is: 3
>
> Revenue from Adults:  80 Number of Seniors is: 2 Revenue from Seniors:
>
> 20

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move your `int numbers = input.nextInt();` into the `while` loop...

Comment: When I have an input of 4 6 20 70 5 7 21 72 
 I get this: 
 Enter Age 
Number of kids is: 1
Revenue from kids:  0
Number of Students is: 1
Revenue from Students:  5
Number of Adults is: 1
Revenue from Adults:  40
Number of Seniors is: 1
Revenue from Seniors:  10
Number of kids is: 2
Revenue from kids:  0
Number of Students is: 2
Revenue from Students:  10
Number of Students is: 3
Revenue from Students:  15
Number of Adults is: 3
Revenue from Adults:  80
Number of Seniors is: 2
Revenue from Seniors:  20

How can i make the output just

Comment: Well, you should move the output after the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should try something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   int kidsPrice = 0;
   int studentPrice=5;
   int adultPrice=20;
   int seniorsPrice = 10;
   int numberOfKids =  0; 
   int numberOfStudents = 0;
   int numberOfAdults = 0 ;
   int numberOfSeniors = 0;

   System.out.println("Enter Age ");
   try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in))
   {
      while (input.hasNext())
      {
         int numbers = input.nextInt();
         if (numbers < 0)
            // TODO
         else if (numbers <= 5)
            ++numberOfKids;
         else if (numbers <= 18)
            ++numberOfStudents;
         else if (numbers <= 65)
            ++numberOfAdults;
         else
            ++numberOfSeniors;
      }
      System.out.println("Number of kids is: " + numberOfKids);
      System.out.println("Revenue from kids:  " + numberOfKids* kidsPrice);
      System.out.println("Number of Students is: " + numberOfStudents);
      System.out.println("Revenue from Students:  " + numberOfStudents * studentPrice);
      System.out.println("Number of Adults is: " + numberOfAdults);
      System.out.println("Revenue from Adults:  " + ++numberOfAdults * adultPrice);
      System.out.println("Number of Seniors is: " + numberOfSeniors);
      System.out.println("Revenue from Seniors:  " + numberOfSeniors * seniorsPrice);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are not reading all the integers actually, you are just reading the first one.
You want to update the `numbers` variable (`number` would be a better name).

It would look similar to:

```
    int number = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        number = input.nextInt();

        .... // do your processing
    }
```